# github clear a repository

Tags: git, github, repository

I have this repository https://github.com/Koushikphy/Interactive-Data-Editor that I want to clear. I just want to clear all history, commits and files but don't want to delete the repo as I have some releases there. I followed few of the suggestion provided here in stack overflow to clear out the repo. It currently shows just 1 commit in github. But I try to clone it now it still downloads all the previous large files. I am confused here. How do I clear out the repo

Answer (score 1):

> don't want to delete the repo as I have some releases there.

That's exactly the problem. You have tags in the repository and these tags prevent garbage collector to remove old (currently hidden) branches. All those branches and blobs are cloned with the tags.

To cleanup the repository you should remove the tags (I'm not sure if their corresponding releases will also be removed; probably they will be). This allows garbage collector to remove old objects from the DB.

Perhaps it's simpler to remove and recreate the repository at GH.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the history:

   ```
   rm -rf .git
   ```
2. Recreate the repos from the current content only:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "Initial commit"
   ```
3. Push to the github remote repos ensuring you overwrite history:

   ```
    git remote add origin git@github.com: YOUR ACCOUNT/YOUR REPOS.git
    git push -u --force origin master
   ```

And you will be good to go.

Comment: i did all that.

Comment: Then you might wanna create a new repo, add all the contents to it and remove this repo.